# Why does my mvc forms authentication with custom entity time out before expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication with a custom entity in my app.

The problem I am experiencing is that my authenticated session expires sooner than the 10 minutes that I expect.

I think i may need to renew the cookie each time an authenticated request comes in for that cookie?

Is that the correct thing to do to keep the session alive?

Thanks - code to follow:

**Web.Config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Admin/Account/LogOn" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

**On sign in**

```
        var identity = new AppIdentity(member.Fullname, member.Id, roles.ToArray());
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(identity.ToString(), false);

        var myCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(identity.ToString(), false);
        myCookie.Domain = string.Format(".{0}", "mydomain.com");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(myCookie);
```

**Global.cs**

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        var ticket = TryDecryptCookie(cookie);

        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var identity = new AppIdentity(ticket);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, identity.Roles);

        Context.User = principal;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the actual timeout?

Comment: it would be the default value of 10 for formsauthentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply extending the expiration when required.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = TryDecryptCookie(cookie);

        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = ticket;

        if (FormsAuthentication.SlidingExpiration)
        {
            newTicket = FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(ticket);
        }

        var identity = new AppIdentity(newTicket);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, identity.Roles);

        Context.User = principal;
    }
```